# How to delete one line if two consecutive lines has same word in bash script?

Tags: bash

How to delete one line if two consecutive lines has same word. For example:

test.txt file contains

```
abc: 400$
abc: 500$
rfg: 300$
rfs: 200$
abc: 400$
rfq: 200$
rfq: 400$
```

Expected test.txt file

```
abc: 500$
rfg: 300$
rfs: 200$
abc: 400$
rfq: 400$
```

Thank you.
Edit: I need to find duplicate word only before ':'. And there will be not more than 2 line containing same word. @blackbrandt

Comment: Look at [sort](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html), check the `-u` flag

Comment: what do you expect as the output if you have more than 2 consecutive lines with the same word (eg, add 2 more lines on the end for `rfq`)?  are we always talking about a single 'word' at the beginning of the line, and before a `:`? or should we be looking for duplicates of any words/tokens on the line (eg, add 2 more lines on the end `abc: 777$` and `def: 777$` (duplicate `777$`)

Comment: @blackbrandt notice their `abc` lines

Comment: Do you always want the last of consecutive lines? And do you otherwise want to retain the existing order?

Comment: I need to delete the first consecutive line every time. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat input
abc: 400$
abc: 500$
rfg: 300$
rfs: 200$
abc: 400$
rfq: 200$
rfq: 400$
$ awk 'p1 != $1 && NR > 1{print last} {last=$0; p1=$1} END {print last} ' input
abc: 500$
rfg: 300$
rfs: 200$
abc: 400$
rfq: 400$
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I need to replace the first consecutive line in the text file if two lines contains same word before ':'

Comment: @arcangel Just change FS to : `awk '...' FS=: input-file`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Probably, I could not describe clearly. I want the result neither in console nor in a new file. I want the result in the same file with the mentioned lines removed.